# How to grep all logged in users?

Tags: linux, grep

How to grep all the logged in users from a user list in Linux (Ubuntu) ?

So far I got to:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Take a look at `man who` and `man w`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as commented above w or who shows you who is logged in..

You could also look at historical/current data looking at lastlog

and lastb for last bad logins.

```
w|grep pts|awk '{print $1}'



for ids in $(w|grep pts|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'); do id=${ids%%_*}; pts=${ids##*_}; actualperson=$(getent passwd $id|awk '{print $5}'); echo "Username: $id  is $actualperson and is logged into $pts";  done;
```

Username: xxx  is  and is logged into pts/0

Username: xxx  is  and is logged into pts/5

```
 for ids in $(w|grep pts|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'); do 
   id=${ids%%_*};
   pts=${ids##*_}; 
   actualperson=$(getent passwd $id|awk '{print $5}'); 
   # echo to your console the persons details
   echo "Username: $id  is $actualperson and is logged into $pts"; 
   # Send a message to person logged in telling them you know their logged in
   echo "I know your logged in $actualperson"|tee /dev/$pts 2>&1>/dev/null;  
 done;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `users` command will probably be helpful. From the man page:

```
users  -  print the user names of users currently logged in to the current host
```